# formula within formula getting CELL/MATCH

Tags: excel, vba

i am doing a `vlookup` of some value

is it possible to get the address of where that value was found?

are there any other ways besides `match` and `cell`?

i do thank you for your answers. but for some reason i am doing this:

```
=cell("address",VLOOKUP(B2,Component!A:F,6,FALSE))
```

and this is not working

i also tried:

```
=address(match(b2,Component!A:F,0))
```

and this did not work either

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this syntax

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH("what you are vlooking up",B1:B30,0),2)
```

Comment: This is ok, but the Cell function is more flexible and gives you access to more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the excel "Cell" function.

Something like the following:

```
Cell("address",VLOOKUP("your vlookup parameters"))
```

[You can find additional information about the cell function here.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/cell-info-type-reference-HP010062392.aspx)

Enjoy!

Comment: i believe that you are missusing this function please reread the link u provided